How do I pass a row to a function using df.apply in Pandas
I have a fairly complicated function that I need to run on each row of my dataframe - lambda functions won't work here.
I want to pass multiple columns from the dataframe to the function.
In my initial test, I tried passing the row and naming a single column (note that I will need to use multiple columns for my program), but received KeyError: 'rec_id'
What do I need to do to pass a row to the function so I can use the different column values (i.e. row.Name or row.rec_id?
A simple sample that shows what I am trying to do:
def testapply(row):
    print(row)
    if row['rec_id']<863238:
        return "X"
    if row['rec_id']>863238 :
        return "Y"

    
data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
        'rec_id': [2532, 863238, 2212]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.apply(testapply)


Use df = df.apply(testapply, axis = 1) Note how axis is specified and also that apply is not done in place.

Perfect thank you!
